Kids trap criminals in forest
I remember seeing this movie before 1997 on VHS tape. It's about an organized crew of kids operating in woods against criminals. They build really big traps and one of them is some sort of spring-fork which kills one of guys, another example is trap which crushes the car on the road with two big logs of wood and the movie's title was about honor. I don't have any other details to add to this. One other thing to keep in mind is that distributors, or illegal copies from 90's do not have proper titles and I failed in finding them using localized title.

You were right about the title; this is likely Edge of Honor from 1991 with Corey Feldman. From IMDb:

A group of [boy]scouts stumble onto a cache of stolen weapons hidden in a forest. They meet up with a girl and get involved with the men who originally stole the weapons. The men try to shoot the scouts every time - but are thwarted at the end.

The scouts fight them with survivalist techniques and wooden traps; one of them is a log trap which crushes a vehicle. It's visible in the trailer around 1:27:



